# cpp inheritance some misconception

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, member, public

here i have some code

```
class A{
 private:
   int a;
 public: 
   void abc()
   { cout << a << endl; }
};
class B : public A
{ };

main() {
 B obj;
 obj.abc(); // it works but why? obj.abc is printing a which should not inherit to class B because it is private.
```

ok so derived class inherited a public function abc() from the base class and that function is trying to output a member variable a that is not a part of derived class because it is private in base class? So how does it do that. this code prints a... but how?

Comment: Private members of the base class *are* members of the derived class. They are not easily accessible from the derived class, but they don't go away.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is `private` to `class A`, but since function `abc` is defined in `class A`, `abc` can make use of `a`.

`B` can make use of `abc` because `abc` is `public` and `B` derives from `A` (publicly).

`a` would not be available to functions defined in `B`.